# Need advice on type constrain design in class template in C++, v11

Tags: c++, types, type-constraints

I'd like to place a POD type constrain on type parameter `T` of class template `A` and then derive another class template `B` from the satisfactory `A`. Besides, `B` is supposed to have different implementation according to constancy of instance of `A`. The purpose of doing all this is about, well you know, for better type checking before runtime.

All I can figure out is a tentative definition of `A`

```
template <typename T, typename POD=void>
class A;
template <typename T>
class A <T, std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value>::type>
{
    //blah...
};
```

so that A can't be instantialized when passing non-POD type, as you might have noticed that partial parameterization does the trick like a type switch.

But I can't figure out how B could be defined. I presume it looks like the following

```
template <typename A?>
class B;
template <>
B<const A?> : public A?
{
    //blah...
};
template <>
B<A?> : public A?
{
    //blah...
};
```

Any brilliant idea?

PS: Personally I tend to be highly critical. But just post how you think this could be done anyway.

Comment: `Besides, B is supposed to have different implementation according to constancy of instance of A.` This doesn't make sense to me. What is *"instance of A"* mean here, in this context? B derives from A, so if `B` is const, then `A` (the sub-object) is also const. Did you mean this? If yes, then why are you trying to make `A` as a template argument to `B`?

Comment: If taking constant A in type parameter of B, then B should be implemented the other way.

Comment: Alright. So you want to derive from  template argument `T` (not `A` actually) where `T` *might* be `A` or `A const`. Is that so?

Comment: Did you try searching for a suitable type trait? Check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_pod/.  You can then use this in some compile time assertion or write code that won't compile if it's false.

Comment: @TonyD well I think the topic is beyond the type trait. Actually I could choose to typedef in class then curry. But I'm looking for possible other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no brilliant idea if the specializations are going to be completely different. You have to go with this:

```
template <typename T>
class B;

template <typename T>
class B<const A<T>> : public A<T>
{

};

template <typename T>
class B<A<T>> : public A<T>
{

};
```

which is *almost* same as you've written yourself except `?` symbol.

You can instantiate this class as:

```
B<A<int>>       x; //it chooses the second specialization
B<const A<int>> y; //it chooses the first specialization
```

See [online demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=29e2102aa33372ac23d70e20e1a7875e-18aa934a8d82d638dde2147aa94cac94). Note that you've forgotten `typename` here:

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value>::type
```

I fixed that too.

If some code in the specializations are going to be same, then you could do some trick in order to *share* the common part, but I cannot suggest anything as I don't know what you're going to put in the specializations.

Comment: So we just declare `class B<const A>` without declaring type parameter of A? I'm confusing and doesn't it look like `class B<const A<//blah...>>` or something else?
I mean is it curry of type parameters?

Comment: Hmm...then this becomes incorrect syntax of partial specialization.